# Getsunlighttimes from the suncalc package gives NAs for "night" and nightEnd" times before 23/07/2023 in R

Tags: r, timezone, na, missing-data

I have a dataframe "diel" with dates ranging from 25/05/2023 to 16/09/2023 and longitude latitude coordinates referring to 5 points within the North Sea.

I used the following code:

```
sun <- getSunlightTimes(data = diel,
                        keep = c("nightEnd", "sunrise", "sunset", "night"), tz = "UTC")
```

Somehow I get NAs for all nightEnd and night times ranging from 25/05/2023 to 22/07/2023 while sunrise and sunset work perfectly. I have tested this with "nauticalDawn" and "nauticalDusk" and here the problem also doesn't occur.

I tried to change the timezone and verify the date format of the date column but the problem persists.

Comment: Please specify the location. Wild guess it has to do with phenomena like midnight sun, polar days?

Comment: the location I have used is in the Belgian part of the North Sea so I would be surprised if there are those phenomena. See below my coordinates
longitude 2.770 latitude 51.665